# Is each bash step create a new shell environment?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

```
  - job: build_package
    dependsOn: test
    displayName: Build Package
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-18.04'
    steps:
      - bash: echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$CONDA/bin"
        displayName: Add Conda to PATH

      - bash: conda env create -f environment.yml --name $(Agent.Id)
        displayName: Create Conda Environment

      - bash: |
          source activate $(Agent.Id)
          conda build . --output-folder ./
        displayName: Build Package In the Build Directory
```

there are 3 bash steps above, I wonder what is the best practice for crating the bash steps, should I group them under the same bash step or like above to make a 3 separate bash steps?

What's the difference between create one bash with several scripts and put those scripts into different bash steps? Is each bash step creates a new shell environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each step/task will creates the new session, so some data will be missing, such as session level environment variable.

So if the scripts are related, you can just run in a task. It also save time.